# Python Mechanize: How to download a file custom buttons

Tags: python, html, mechanize

I'm trying to download a file from website but in page source there are no tags related to buttons or forms. They are using custom buttons. The page source is like

```
var LABELS={"kind":"Template type","format":"File format","btn_generate":"Generate template","btn_cancel":"Cancel","btn_start":"Start import","btn_back":"Back to overview","legend":"Mandatory fields are <span class='marked'>blue</span>"};
```

from the above code `"btn_generate":"Generate template"` this is my button.

Normally if I click on the button in webpage it will download a file.

I'm parsing the page source and getting the value of `"btn_generate"` as `"Generate template"`.

Now I want to apply button click on this `"btn_generate":"Generate template"` to download a file. As, not sure whether it is possible or not.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mechanize
from cookies import *
myCookie = Cookiee().get_cookies()
req = six.moves.urllib.request.Request(
                url='https://xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/import?PAGE=1',
                headers={
                    'Cookie': '; '.join([k+'='+v for k, v in            myCookie.items()])
                }
            )
response = six.moves.urllib.request.urlopen(req)
text = bytes(response.read()).decode('utf-8', errors="replace")
javascript = re.findall(
            r'<script language=\'javascript\'>(.+?)</script>',
            text,
            flags=re.S
            )[0]
 jvars = javascript.split('\nvar ')

 labels = [x for x in jvars if x.startswith("LABELS")][0]

 jsonoverview = json.loads(labels.split('=', 1)[1].rstrip(';\n'))
 btn_name = jsonoverview['btn_generate']
 print('btn_name',btn_name)

 br = mechanize.Browser()
```

HTML page as:

```
<div id="contentWrapper"><table id="pageTitleBox"><tbody><tr><td><div id="backBtn" class="goog-custom-button goog-inline-block" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Back to overview" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-inner-box"><div class="back-icon goog-inline-block"></div><span></span></div></div></div></td><td><div id="pageTitle">Import template</div></td></tr></tbody></table><table id="topControlBox"><tbody><tr><td class="rlabel dropBox">Template type:</td><td class="dropBox"><div id="isNewTicketDropDownBox"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button" title="" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-inner-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-caption">for updating</div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div></td><td class="rlabel dropBox">File format:</td><td class="dropBox"><div id="formatDropDownBox"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button" title="" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-inner-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-caption">Excel</div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div></td><td><div id="startBtn" class="goog-custom-button goog-inline-block" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Start import" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-inner-box"><div class="action-icon goog-inline-block"></div><span>Start import</span></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="btnPanel"><table><tbody><tr><td><div id="generateBtn" class="goog-custom-button goog-inline-block" role="button" tabindex="0" title="Generate template" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-custom-button-inner-box"><div class="save-icon goog-inline-block"></div><span>Generate template</span></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

Comment: please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you find the form in forms? `for form in br.forms() print form` Then you can submit the form.

Comment: there are no forms and no button tags in source.

Comment: @Jithin i updated with code

Comment: please provide the correct url so that i can help you in a better way.

Comment: @Jithin as i cannot share url. I updated with html . Please have a look.